# Add href that selects an option select tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have two pages: A and B.
On page A I have three links:

```
<a href="#link-to-option-A">A</a>
<a href="#link-to-option-B">B</a>
<a href="#link-to-option-C">C</a>
```

On page B I have three options in selector:

```
<select>
   <option value="A">Option A</option>
   <option value="B">Option B</option>
   <option value="C">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Now I need such a thing: If user clicks on A page on href C then user should be redirected to page B and there automatically should be selected option C in selector. I don't have enough knowledge to do this using JavaScript or something.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

On page A I start to use form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="soflissaxeli"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

on page B:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('select').find('option[value=<?php echo $_POST["soflissaxeli"]; ?
>]').attr('selected','selected');
});
</script>
```